# C programming: Error in writing values of a particular column from a file to another file

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault

I want to store the values of 6th column from a file to another file.

Following is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned int number_of_lines = 0;
    int n6 = 0;
    char line[1000];
    char line2[100];
    char line3[1000];
    char *pch;
    int l;
    char *pch2;
    char c[6] = " N ";
    FILE *fp = fopen("1PGB.pdb", "r");                      // This opens the 1PGB.pdb in read-only mode
    FILE *op = fopen("out", "w");                           // This opens the out file in write mode
    char lastline[100]=" ";
    if(fp == NULL || op == NULL)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file.");
        exit(1);
      }
    else  
      {                                                   // This loop is for printing only the lines containing " N " into out file
       while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != 0)
          {
            if((pch = strstr (line, c))!= 0)
            fprintf(op, "%s", line);
          }
      }
     fclose(fp);                                         // Closes 1PGB.pdb
     fclose(op);                                         // Closes out file
     FILE *ip = fopen("out", "r");                       // Opens out file in read mode
     FILE *op2 = fopen("out2", "w");                // Opens out2 file in write mode
     if(!ip)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        exit(1);
      }
       while (fgets(line3, sizeof(line3),  ip) != 0)      
       {
        sscanf(line3, "%*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %d", &n6);
        fprintf(op2, "%d\n", n6);                 // Writes only the column 6th of out to out2 file
       }
       // Stores the value in last line, 6th column in variable "l"
       {
      while (fgets(line2, sizeof(line2), ip) !=0)
          if ((pch2 = strstr (line2, c)) != NULL)
          {
              strcpy(lastline, line2);

          }
      }
     fclose(ip);
     if(*lastline)
       {
        strtok(lastline," "); //skip first field
        int i =0;
        for(i=0;i<4;i++) // skip next 4 fields (5 in total)
        strtok(NULL," ");
        sscanf(strtok(NULL," "),"%d",&l);
        printf("Number of residues: %d\n", l); //print the 6th field
           } 
fclose(op2);    
    return 0;
}
```

If I try to extract column 6 from 1PGB.pdb to out2 file, it works perfectly fine. But in this case, when try to extract that from an output file to a text file, it gives segmentation fault.

Also, it was working fine before I added this segment of code:

```
 while (fgets(line3, sizeof(line3),  ip) != 0)      
       {
        sscanf(line3, "%*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %d", &n6);
        fprintf(op2, "%d\n", n6);                 // Writes only the column 6th of out to out2 file
       }
```

I'll be thankful if someone points out where am I getting it wrong.

Comment: You need to check the return of your `sscanf` calls to insure you are actually getting the desired number of conversions (e.g. `int cnv; cnv=sscanf(line3, "%*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %d", &n6); if (!cnv)...` I suspect you hit a blank line or something similar and `n6` isn't what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with the program, you have. However, the error `segmentation fault` you are seeing is because of of `sscanf()`, as you you mentioned.

> - In an ideal scenario, you are expected to also check for `EOF` in
>     return value of `fgets()`.
> - You would also be writing `sscanf()` as `sscanf(line, "%s %s %s %s %s
>     %d", &n1,&n2,&n3,&n4,&n5,&n6);` You might want to capture all the 5 strings. And
>     of 'course you need to define variables `n1,n2....,n5` first before use.

Once you make these changes, I am pretty sure `segmentation fault` will stop bugging you. I hope this will help you in correcting your program eventually.

**UPDATE:**

Just now I realized by looking at your other post, you don't want to read 5 strings then an integer from your `out` file. You may want to read `string integer string string string integer .....` in an order. So for this you need to use `sscanf(line, "%s %d %s %s %s %d", &n1,&n2,&n3,&n4,&n5,&n6);` Once you read the required values and stored in respective variables, you can use only `n6` wherever you need it. Rest of the variables you can choose not to use.